# CakePHP: how to use a model in the app_controller

Tags: cakephp, controller, models

Iv got a method in a model that I want to be executed everytime a page is requested so I think I need to call it from the app_controller but can't seem to get it to work. The model i want to use is called Blacklist and it has a method in it called check_blacklist() which is what I want to run every time a page is requested. Does anyone know how I should do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, one way to do that would be adding:

```
var $uses = array('Blacklist');
```

In your `AppController` class.

Perhaps a better solution is using a CakePHP built-in method called: [loadModel](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Controller.html#_loadModel), like this:

```
$this->loadModel('Blacklist');
```

If you add `Blacklist` in the `$uses` array in your `AppController`, it will be available in all of your controllers, `loadModel` just loads the Model for a specific task.

Comment: in which method in the app controller would you call loadModel so that it loads everytime?

Comment: Use a controller callback: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::beforeFilter

Answer (score 3):

Try to avoid using the `$uses` array as it adds some overhead to all actions, whether or not the model is used in that action.

As Pawel says, you can use `$this->loadModel('Blacklist');` It should be located in the action, say view, just before `$this->Blacklist->check_blacklist()`

e.g.

```
function view($id)
{
    if($id)
    {
        $this->loadModel('Blacklist');
        $this->Blacklist->check_blacklist();
        ...
    }
}
```

If this is very widely used, I'd probably write the function on app_model.

---

Edit:

Use of loadModel is covered here: http://book.cakephp.org/view/845/loadModel

Answer (score 1):

$ModelName = ClassRegistry::init('ModelName');

$ModelName->find();

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, due to [bug #858](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/858), your best bet is to avoid using `loadModel()` in AppController for now, unless you aren't using any plugins (quite possible). The solution I used to replace `$uses` was along the lines of:

```
$this->Blacklist = ClassRegistry::init('Blacklist');
$this->Blacklist->check_blacklist();
```

Note that you should put this in your `beforeFilter()` or `beforeRender()` ([see the cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/984/Callbacks)) - depending on when you want it executed...

If you'd like to use that same code in other sites, or have it fire earlier in the loading chain, you might consider a Component - putting the same code in your Component [`initialize()` function](http://book.cakephp.org/view/998/MVC-Class-Access-Within-Components), or `startup()` function if the point in the load chain is less critical.

Comment: That's a bit of a heavy handed statement - not far off saying 'because there are bugs it would be best to avoid using CakePHP for a while'. I haven't ever needed to use plugins in a CakePHP application, and I've built a few. My reading of #858 is that it would be inadvisable to use loadModel in the plugin itself.

Comment: If you're going to do this in the beforeFilter, you may as well use $uses.

Comment: @Leo - It should be clear that this is an alternative solution in response to the same problem under the given conditions, namely, running an instance with plugins. Also, certain things were made simpler by removing my last usage of `$uses`.

Comment: The OP doesn't mention plugins. I only mentioned plugins because you did and 858 doesn't say anything about avoiding the use of loadModel outside of a plugin. The whole point of loadModel is that you can load a model on the fly where you need it and not everywhere else.

Comment: Plugin controllers extend AppController. The code in AppController is therefore called from the context of the Plugin.